# Security Relearn for 2006 Chevy Aveo

Tags: chevrolet, aveo

I had to replace a faulty ECM in a 2006 Chevy Aveo, and I ordered the part pre-programmed (based on my VIN and possibly some other info). I've installed the part and have began the security relearn process, but no security light turns on. The parking brake light, check engine light, battery light, and seatbelt lights turn on, but no others.

The process I've started for the relearn starts with turning the key to attempt to start the car, then turning back to ON until the security light turns off (which should take about 10 minutes). The car has a red dot for a security light, but it does not turn on with this procedure.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?